# Show that there exists two real numbers $a,b,q$ such $q<a≤r≤b<q+1$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $r$ be a rational number and not an integer. Show that there exists two real numbers $a$ and $b$ and an **intger** $q$ such $$q<a≤r≤b<q+1$$

Of course I would like that $a,b,q$ depends on $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take that $a=b=r$, $q=[r]$, which is the biggest intger that less than $r$ .

Answer (score 0):

Show there is an integer $q$ satisfying $q\leq r < q+1$.

Then since $r$ is not an integer, $q < r < q+1$.

Consider $q$ and $r$, there is a real number $a$ between them.